# Page Scrolling Effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I was trying to clone the UI of an app with HTML and CSS. In the app, there is a sliding effect which it uses to toggle between two parts.

While I was doing this, I was able to create the interface, but unable to make the sliding effect function as it should normally. The scrolling effect is meant to stop scrolling to the rightward or leftward side when it is at the right and left tabs respectively.

I am looking for possible ways of correcting this, so that the scrolling can function effectively as it should be.

[The default page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gbGf.png)

[The evening tab page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coO7u.png)

[What appears when the evening tab or morning tab is pressed when one of the tabs is clicked repeatedly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuuB1.png)

[That is the tab with the brown border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoagg.png)

```
<head>
<script defer src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div class="head">
<span class="nav"> 
<i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> <span class="athkar">Athkar</span>
</span>
<i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
<div class="time">                
<button onclick="slide('morning')">Morning</button>
<button onclick="slide('evening')">Evening</button>
</div>
</div>

<div class="content">
<div class="pages">
<div class="page morning">  
<div class="main">
<div class="container">
<div class="border">
<div class="number">1-12</div>
</div>
<span class="cont">سُبْحَانَ اللَّهِ وَبِحَمْدِهِ ، عَدَ دَخَلْقِهِ،
وَرِضَا نَفْسِهِ ، وَزِنَةَ عَرْشِهِ،
وَمِدَادَ كَلِمَاتِهِ</span>
<small>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, labore!</small>
</div>
<div class="counter">
<div class="fa-solid">
<i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i></div>
<div class="btn-shell">
<button><span id="present">0</span>/3</button>
</div>
<div class="fa-solid">
<i class="fa fa-play"></i></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page evening">             
<div class="main">
<div class="container">
<div class="border">
<div class="number">2-12</div>
</div>
<span class="cont">سُبْحَانَ اللَّهِ وَبِحَمْدِهِ ، عَدَ دَخَلْقِهِ،
وَرِضَا نَفْسِهِ ، وَزِنَةَ عَرْشِهِ،
وَمِدَادَ كَلِمَاتِهِ</span>
<small>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, labore!</small>
</div>
<div class="counter">
<div class="fa-solid">
<i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i></div>
<div class="btn-shell">
<button><span id="present">0</span>/3</button>
</div>
<div class="fa-solid">
<i class="fa fa-play"></i></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

body, .counter {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px){
    body {
        display: block;
    }
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
  
  body {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none; 
  }

.head {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

.nav {
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    left: 45px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.fa-arrow-left {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-250%);
}

.fa-cog {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.athkar {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.time {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(170%);
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.time button {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.556);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    /* border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(193, 207, 33);     */
    background-color: transparent;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.556);
}

.content {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.pages {
    display: flex;
    width: 200%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.page {
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.main {
    background-color: rgb(220, 226, 199);
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 95%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 15px auto;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 1px rgb(191, 176, 156);
}

.fa-solid:active {
    scale: 0.9;
}

.container {
    background-color: rgb(227, 238, 184);
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: right;
}

.border {
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid goldenrod;
    border-right: 1px solid goldenrod;
    border-left: 1px solid goldenrod;
    height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

span.cont {
    display: block;
}

small {
    color: rgb(135, 139, 44);
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.number {
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.counter {
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.counter .btn-shell,.counter button {
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.counter button {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(120, 122, 119, 0.401);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1.9px 3px 3.5px -1px #dddddd;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -1.9px 3px 3.5px -1px #dddddd;
    box-shadow: inset -1.9px 3px 3.5px -1px #dddddd;
}

.counter button:active {
    background-color: rgba(85, 130, 85, 0.483);
}

.fa-solid {
    background-color: green;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

```
const pages = document.querySelectorAll(".page");
const translateUnit = 100;
let translate = 0;

slide = (direction) => {

    direction === "evening" ? translate -= translateUnit : translate += translateUnit;

    pages.forEach(
        pages => (pages.style.transform = `translateX(${translate}%)`)
    )

}
```

I tried creating a page scroll effect on one HTML page, I used some .js codes to do this, I intended for the code not to function when the present tab is displaying, but is still does which changed the result I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if(direction === "evening")
 {translate = -100} 
else {
if(direction === "morning") {
  translate = 0 }
```

let me know how that works.